# Undefined in React Context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a problem with context in React. This is my context code.

```
import {useContext, createContext } from 'react';
import { GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithPopup, signOut, onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth'
import { firebaseAuth } from '../Firebase/Config.js'

const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthContextProvider = ({children}) => {
    const googleSignIn = async () => {
        const provider = await new GoogleAuthProvider();
        signInWithPopup(firebaseAuth, provider);
      }
    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={googleSignIn}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

export const UserAuth = () => {
    return useContext(AuthContext);
}
```

and there is where I'm using this context.

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import reactLogo from './assets/react.svg'
import viteLogo from '/vite.svg'
import UploadImage from './Firebase/UploadImage.jsx'
import './App.css'
import {GoogleButton} from 'react-google-button'
import { AuthContextProvider, UserAuth } from './Context/AuthContext.jsx'

function App() {

  const googleSignIn = UserAuth();

    const handleGoogleSignIn = async () => {
      console.log(googleSignIn);
      try {
        await googleSignIn();
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }

  return (
    <div>
    <AuthContextProvider>
      <UploadImage />
      <div className="HandleGoogleSignIn">
        <GoogleButton onClick={handleGoogleSignIn} />
      </div>
    </AuthContextProvider>
  </div>  
  )
}

export default App
```

Do you have any idea why googleSignIn is undefined? I don't see any mistakes. Should be fine, but isn't. I'm just starting learning React.

Comment: The `<AuthContextProvider>` needs to be *higher* up the component tree than where you use it. They can't be in the same component. So either move the provider up to a parent component above App, or move where you call `UserAuth` down to a child component.

Comment: @NicholasTower already answered your question you are trying to access the function outside of the context. in your case you need to wrap app component in the context or move the code thats accessing stuff from context down into lower component

Answer (score 0):

Here is some suggestions you can try:

1. Remove the await from const provider = await new GoogleAuthProvider(); and rather add await in signInWithPopup(firebaseAuth, provider);
   So, the code will look like:

```js
import { useContext, createContext } from 'react';
import { GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithPopup, signOut, onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth'
import { firebaseAuth } from '../Firebase/Config.js'

const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthContextProvider = ({
  children
}) => {
  const googleSignIn = async() => {
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    await signInWithPopup(firebaseAuth, provider);
  }
  return ( <
    AuthContext.Provider value = { googleSignIn } > { children } </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}

export const UserAuth = () => {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}
```

2. Here are a few things to check:

**Firebase Configuration:**
Ensure that your Firebase configuration (firebaseAuth in Config.js) is set up correctly.

**Firebase Imports:**
Double-check that your Firebase imports are correct, especially the signInWithPopup function.

**Check for Errors:**
Open your browser's developer tools (usually by pressing F12 or right-clicking and selecting "Inspect") and check the console for any error messages. This can provide valuable information about what might be going wrong.

**Ensure Firebase is Initialized:**
Make sure that your Firebase app is initialized correctly and that the configuration is loaded before attempting to use it.